# Transform timestamp to date&time

Tags: sql, timestamp, presto

I have a timestamp that comes in such from: **2021-12-20T18:00:55.126X**

I want to change the form and show only the date and time so it would become something like **2021-12-20 18:00:55** The challenge is that I would also like to show the date&time + X days. For example, add 5 days and I want it to show **2021-12-25 18:00:55**. Is there a good solution for a case like this?

*I work with Presto

Answer (score 1):

Remove T and X, cast to timestamp and add interval 5 day:

```
select cast(regexp_replace('2021-12-20T18:00:55.126X','^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})X$','$1 $2') as timestamp) + interval '5' day
```

Result:

```
2021-12-25 18:00:55.126
```

And if you want it as string without milliseconds you can format it:

```
select format_datetime(( cast(regexp_replace('2021-12-20T18:00:55.126X','^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})X$','$1 $2') as timestamp) + interval '5' day),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Result:

```
2021-12-25 18:00:55
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove `X` from the string and use `from_iso8601_timestamp` to parse the timestamp:

```sql
select from_iso8601_timestamp(replace('2021-12-20T18:00:55.126X', 'X', ''))
```

To add days you can use either `interval` or `date_add`:

```
select now() + interval '1' day, date_add('day', 1, now())
```